# No imprimir un objeto

Tags: php

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Accept: */*",
   "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0"
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$resp2 = json_decode($resp);

$paraGuardar = '';

    foreach($resp2->orders as $orden){
        foreach($orden as $key=> $item){
           $paraGuardar .= print_r($item, true);
           echo($item);
           echo '*';
        }
        echo '<br>'.'<br>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: ¿Y qué objeto no quieres imprimir? ¿Qué nos puedes decir de él?

Comment: "current_subtotal_price_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "123.43",
          "currency_code": "EUR"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "123.43",
          "currency_code": "EUR"
        }
      },

Comment: este tipo de objetos, son datos de unos pedidos

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo mínimo de tu JSON indicando qué objeto quieres ignorar? No queda claro si quieres ignorarlo en el primer bucle o en el segundo.

Comment: "id": 3810641608870,
      "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Order/3810641608870",
      "app_id": 1354745,
      "browser_ip": null,
      "buyer_accepts_marketing": false,"current_subtotal_price_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "123.43",
          "currency_code": "EUR"
        },

Comment: La idea es recorrerlos y que los imprima pero que ignoré por completo los objetos, ya que hay muchos de este estilo

Comment: quizas poniendo un if para que, si no es objeto, te lo imprima?  puedes revisar https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-object.php, por si puede servirte

Comment: A ver, la estructura que nos compartes [no es un JSON válido](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), necesitamos un ejemplo mínimo y verificable que incluya por ejemplo dos elementos de tu array. Tampoco queda claro aún qué es lo que se debe ignorar exactamente.

Comment: Para proveer más información a tu pregunta, pulsa en [edit]. El código en los comentarios es ilegible. Y como te han indicado, agrega un [repro].

Comment: @Abi ¿Como son los objetos que SI necesitas que se impriman? ¿Que tienen en común los objetos que quisieras que NO se impriman? o ¿ Como diferencias cuales si y cuales no?

Comment: En un php tengo un código en el que está la url de unos datos de pedidos (son muchos) esos pedidos tiene incluidos objetos, y la idea es que se imprima los que NO sean objetos y que por pantalla salga los que No son objetos, ya que hay mucha información irrelevante

Comment: sabes que clave identifica a esos objetos? si es asi, solo tienes que indicar esa clave en un if. Si no tiene esa clave, lo imprimes.

Comment: por ej: si no quieres imprimir el objeto `current_subtotal_price_set`, puedes poner un if dentro del bucle, de manera que `if(! $key === 'current_subtotal_price_set`))` te imprima el resto de cosas

Comment: ¿como puedo identificar esos objetos? y el if, lo pongo en el segundo bucle o como?